# can you tell me what kind of animal this is?

Tags: species-identification, zoology

[image]

I found this skull over 2 years ago and i have been unable to find another like it or even come across someone who knows what it is. i live in south mississippi and the animal it came from looked like a deer, or even a dog, it was almost completely decomposed. I have been curious for 2 years now and have posted this before on other sites with no luck. someone help please .

Answer (score 5):

Looks rather like a boar skull, which would make sense in Mississippi (especially Southern Mississippi), [where their population has been growing for decades](http://wildpiginfo.msstate.edu/).

[image: Wild Boar hybrid Skull, female, lateral view, from http://www.skullsite.co.uk]